# What is the current size of Ethereum's world state?

Tags: state

I'm interested in the STATE size, not the size of the chain.

Comment: https://notes.ethereum.org/@vbuterin/verkle_and_state_expiry_proposal#:~:text=The%20Ethereum%20state%20size%20is,half%20that%20amount%20per%20year.

Comment: It's a little outdated but it's something. Thanks!

Comment: Have you been able to find an answer? Wondering about the same question and also the rate of growth too